# Could weak_ptr from make_shared be implemented with a single pointer instead of two?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

The size of a shared_ptr is the size of two raw pointers, one to the resource and another to the control block that keeps reference counts. Ordinarily the control block is allocated separately from the resource but with make_shared it's likely that the control block is allocated with the resource, I'm (guessing) something like:

```
template <typename T>
struct ResourceAndControlBlock
{
struct ControlBlock{
      int weakReferences, strongReferences;
}controlBlock;    
char obj[sizeof(T)]; // Object can exist here or not
    
};
```

And when you do make_shared{} it returns a shared_ptr, which contains two pointers, one to char obj[] (the resource), and one to 'controlBlock'.

I was wondering whether it could be implemented in this way, make_shared returns a shared pointer with only one pointer, to the resource, and then when needing to access the information in the control block, to check if the resource is still valid, or to decrement any references, it can access it with the 'resource pointer' minus sizeof(ControlBlock).

Is the reason why this is a bad idea just that it complicates things having two different types of shared pointers, one with two pointers and one with only one? Or is there something wrong with doing it this way?

Edit: I just remembered about the strict aliasing rule, is it that the pointer to resource can't be cast to a ControlBlock pointer to read the control block?

Comment: You've just made a new type, not changed the implementation of an existing type.   The answer is no, you cannot re-implement the existing type as you suggest because of the exact reasons you listed.

Comment: @xaxxon You mean because there would be two different types of pointers? What if a person were implementing one themselves, where every shared_ptr was of the make_shared (ie., the control block would be guaranteed to be sizeof(ControlBlock) before the resource? There's no issues with strict aliasing I think? I mean casting the resource pointer to void*, minusing sizeof(ControlBlock) and casting to ControlBlock*?

Comment: Sure.  And if you're worried about aliasing, the type could contain a pointer to a struct that has both the control block and the data.

Comment: @Ah, yes, thank you. I like the make_shared version (with the control block allocated with the resource). there is one disadvantage of this method which is that the entire allocation isn't deallocated unless there are no more weak references, as opposed to a separate control block, but I think the advantages are much better. And if it could be implemented with only one pointer, even better.

Comment: Other considerations: constructors 8 through 11 as listed [on cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr). Each of these constructors could be given a result of `make_shared` as an argument. *(So that people who know the terms don't have to follow the link: constructor 8 is the aliasing constructor, while 9 through 11 are templated to allow construction from compatible pointer types.)*

Comment: For a question like this, sometimes the most educational approach is to try it and see what problems you encounter. Is the problem you foresee just a complication, or will it shut down your effort cold?

Comment: @JaMiT Aliasing constructor? So its control block pointer points to a control block for one object, but it's pointer points to another object? What's the use of that?

Comment: @Zebrafish According to that cppreference page, the typical use of an aliasing constructor is something like `struct A { int b; };` followed by `auto ptr = make_shared<A>(); shared_ptr<int> aliased{ptr, &(ptr->b)};`. You get a shared pointer to the member, still with a control block in the same block of allocated memory.

Answer (score 0):

> The size of a shared_ptr is the size of two raw pointers, one to the resource and another to the control block that keeps reference counts.

While this is one possible implementation of a shared pointer, it is not the only one.  Another possible implementation would be a single pointer (to the control block) and have the pointer to the resource in the control block.  The drawback of this is that dereferencing the shared pointer requires two (dependent) memory accesses which is slightly slower.

A hybrid implementation could have a pointer to the resource in the control block and two pointers (to control block and resource) in a shared_ptr but only one pointer (to the control block) in a weak_ptr, since the weak_ptr requires accessing the control block (to see if the object is still live) before trying to dereference the resource pointer anyways.